# Difference between <Flags> and <FlagsAttribute()>

Tags: vb.net, attributes, flags

On the [MSDN Enum Class page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zt1ybx4.aspx), there are a couple examples of using Enums with the Flags Attribute. One is written:

```
<Flags> Public Enum Pets As Integer
```

and another is written:

```
<FlagsAttribute()> Enum Colors
```

The text treats these examples as equivalent. Is there a difference between these forms? Are the parentheses required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely equivalent. The conventions are as follows

1. You don't need the Attribute suffix (ergo the Flags vs FlagsAttribute)
2. You don't need the parenthesis as it's implied if you aren't passing arguments to the attribute.

Full rules can be [found in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx). Guidelines for [attribute usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab31zeh.aspx).

Comment: Thanks; the MSDN pages are really inconsistent in using the Attribute suffix.

Answer (score 2):

Flags is shorthand for FlagsAttribute when you apply for an element.
Flags denote enum has flags elements